# Node-Red send character to terminal - e.g. send space to pause/play OMXplayer

Tags: keypress, node-red, omxplayer

I am controlling OMXPlayer from Node-Red, starting it using the exec node - works fine.  I would also like to do the equivalent of a keypress to control it - e.g. space to pause/play and "q" to quit.  Sending a character to the exec node does not work.  I could not find any node to perform this function.  Hence would appreciate any guidance on how I might do this.  Thank you.  Mike

Comment: For s long running app you need to use the Daemon node not exec

Comment: I struggled to get this working with Daemon.  It seems to want to have the process running all the time.  It is not clear how to start it (if not started on deploy).

Comment: I have just found a mechanism to stop OMXplayer - using dbuscontrol.sh.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution eventually.  I tried a node.js module called simpleomxcontrol and pulled this into NodeRed. This would start the player but not pause or stop it.

I then tied dbuscontrol.sh .  It appeared to have a problem pulling in the 'stop' argument.  So I edited dbuscontrol so it would only implement stop (no arguments required)(and send to exec node).  I expect I could also edit dbuscontrol to implement pause or other requirements as single scripts if I ever need these.

Thank you to all who helped me find an answer.  Mike